# How to horizontally align-center only for small and medium screens only using Zurb Foundation flex grid

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, zurb-foundation

I would like to `align-center` the two columns only for `medium down` sized screens and not for large. This used to be available with `small-centered` and `medium-centered` but doesn't work with **[Zurb Foundation's Flex Grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flex-grid.html)**.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 large-7 columns">
    <p>A: Left on large, centred otherwise</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 large-5 columns>
    <p>B: Right on large, centred otherwise</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've been looking for something like `align-center-middle` but don't seem to be able to find any. I can create a custom class however I'd prefer to use the built in option if one exists.

[image: flex grid example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no one knows of a way to do this with built in Zurb Foundation functionality, I added these helper classes to my project:

```
.align-center-small {
  @include breakpoint(small only) {
    -webkit-box-pack: center !important;
    -ms-flex-pack: center !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
  }
}

.align-center-medium {
  @include breakpoint(medium only) {
    -webkit-box-pack: center !important;
    -ms-flex-pack: center !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
  }
}

.align-center-large {
  @include breakpoint(large only) {
    -webkit-box-pack: center !important;
    -ms-flex-pack: center !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a great idea (no idea why Foundation 6 hasn't got this functionality, seems so basic. Nearest I could find was: https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/typography-helpers.html - but ONLY has .medium-text-center - I need .small-text-center!)

So I tried your code above and get 'mixin breakpoint not found' error ... is there some code missing here? (disclaimer - frontend noob here)